# SQL Query to group records and return them as a list in a many-to-one relationship

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having a bit of trouble with using SQLAlchemy to its full potential in a Python application using Flask, and understanding how many-to-one relationships work and how they can be utilized.

I'm working with a database of songs and artists with a schema that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE song (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(64),
artist_id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE artist (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(64)
);
```

Or, through Python SQLAlchemy, it looks like this:

```
class Song(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    kws_id = db.Column(db.String(32))
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id'))
    artist = db.relationship('Artist', backref='songs', foreign_keys=[artist_id])

class Artist(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

`song.artist_id` refers to the column `artist.id`; this is a many-to-one relationship where many songs can refer to one artist.

**I'm hoping that I can have the results displayed as:**

```
artist:
  song1
  song2
  song3
artist2:
  song4
  song5
...
```

Or, in JSON, roughly: `{artist: [song1, song2, song3], artist2: [song4, song5]}`. (The end goal is to return this in an AJAX paginated response through Flask).

**Basically, I'm hoping that I can have a dict of artists which contains a list of songs; and if I were to run a search on a specific song, it would return a dict of the same structure, with only matching songs.**

If I want to run a query and select all songs from all artists, I can simply query all artists and then use the `backref` attribute to get all of the songs.

```
artists = Artist.query.all()
for artist in artists:
  songs = artist.songs
  # construct json: artist => song
```

However, **I'm struggling with a solution for filtering songs while keeping the data structure it returns intact.**

#### Some solutions I've tried so far:

**I could do it manually in Python, and simply have the query return the original list:**

```
artists = Artist.query.all()
for artist in artists:
  for song in artist.songs
    if song == "search": # or starts with, or something else
       # this is a song we want to match
```

I could build a json response from this, but this feels like I'm using SQL like a list rather than a query language-- not using it to its fullest potential and sacrificing speed.

---

**I could query the artist table and filter by song:**

```
q = Artist.query
q = q.join(Artist.songs)
q = q.filter(Song.name.like("%" + search + "%"))
# q is a query which will return a list of artists
# each artist has the aforementioned backref for a list of song
```

This searches, but returns the entire artist for every result. For example, in this dataset:

```
{artist1: [song1, song2, song3], artist2: [song4, song5, song6]}
```

A search for `"song1"` would return artist1, and the backref will contain all of the songs for artist1. The json I construct would be `{artist1: [song1, song2, song3]}` rather than `{artist1: song1}`, which would be ideal.

I'm not sure if there's a way to improve this in order to filter out songs I don't want, or if querying the artist table is the wrong way to go.

---

Another method I've explored is **doing the query on the song list:**

```
q = Song.query
q = q.join(Artist)
q = q.filter(Song.name.like("%" + i + "%"))
```

However, in this case, q.all() is a list of songs, and although they contain the artist name, they are not "grouped" by the artist name (I would have to do manual work to make a list of all songs with the same artist name, for every artist). i.e. the best I could do is:

```
[song1, song2, song3, song4]
```

Or,

```
artists = {}
for song in songs:
    artists[song.artist.name].append(song.name)
    # or initialize artists[song.artist.name] = [song.name,]
```

All of these solutions I've tried seem to involve some sort of manual task on part of the Python program, and I feel there should be a way to improve my solution to rely more heavily on SQL. **Is there a way to query a table and return groups, grouped/listed by the "one" part of the many-to-one relationship, only matching the "many"s which match a certain criteria?**

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result

Comment: @IljaEverilä ah! This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!!!

Comment: @IljaEverilä If you want to make your comment into an answer so I can accept it, that would be awesome!

Comment: There are some existing Q/A that are fairly similar to what you're after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504889/filter-sqlalchemy-query-result-objects-one-to-many-attribute, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924347/filtering-relationships-in-sql-alchemy and perhaps this could be closed as a duplicate of either one of those, or both. That way your question would serve as a sign post for people looking for an answer.