# How to access only filtered objects when filtering on joined tables in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy for the first time and I have an unexpected behavior in reading results of a query.

Let's say these are my database models:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __table__ = "parents"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __table__ = "children"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.id"))
    did_homework = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

When I query the database like this:

```py
parents = session.query(Parent).join(Parent.children).filter(Child.did_homework == True).all()
good_children = parents[0].children
```

I expected all `good_children` to have `did_homework` set to `True`.

But it seems the query returns all parents which have at least one Child with `did_homework` set to `True` and then when I access `parents[0].children` I get all `children` of that `parent`, not just the ones that satisfy my criteria.

I have tried querying like this:

```py
result = (
        db.query(Parent, Child)
        .filter(Parent.id == Child.parent_id)
        .filter(Child.did_homework == True)
        .all()
    )
```

which gives the expected tuples as the `result` (every `Child` in the tuple has `did_homework == True`), but every `Parent` in the tuple still has all `children`, not just the ones that did their homework.

**Question**:
Is there a way of writing a query that would assign only the `children` which are not filtered out to the `parent` they belong to?
So that when I write: `good_children = parents[0].children` I could be sure all objects in `good_children` have `did_homework` set to `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528931/sqlalchemy-filter-the-objects-from-relationship-when-accessed?rq=1) with an answer that didn't work for me, but with a small modification I managed to do it:

```py
parents = (
        db.query(Parent)
        .join(Child)
        .filter(Child.did_homework == True)
        .options(contains_eager("children"))
        .all()
    )
```